# C++ STL stack: When is it safe to pop()

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Consider:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

class Abc {
    int x = 5;
    public:
    void display() {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::stack<Abc> S;
    S.emplace();

    auto obj = S.top();
    S.pop();
    obj.display();
    return 0;
}
```

From: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/pop/, "This calls the removed element's destructor".
Also, from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/top/, stack.top() returns by reference.

If `S.top()` returned by reference and if `S.pop()` destructed the object, why doesn't `obj.display()` fail?

I know that stack calls the `back()` and `pop_back()` methods of the underlying container. By extension, why doesn't that fail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`auto obj = S.top();` *copy initializes* `obj` from `S.top()`. It's a copy of the then removed element.

You code snippet has well defined behavior.

It will be undefined if you were to take a reference, like `auto& obj = S.top();`

Comment: @j4nu5, like my last remark says. It will be undefiend behavior, since the element is referenced and used after being destroyed